# How to add extension to Client Hello HTTPS (okHTTP)

Tags: java, android, ssl, https, okhttp

Is there any possibility of adding my own extension into Client Hello Handshake Protocol ? If yes, how should I go about it ?

[image]

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK this is not generally possible.

The alpn-boot does something similar to what you are trying to do.  However it shows the awkwardness of trying this as they need to be included in the JVM boot classpath and because of extending non-public API classes, there are builds specific to JVM versions.

https://github.com/jetty-project/jetty-alpn/blob/master/alpn-boot/src/main/java/sun/security/ssl/HelloExtensions.java

http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/alpn-chapter.html